# If Allah exposes some sin of someone, does it mean Allah hates that person?

Tags: allah, islamic-philosophy, sin

I basically have three questions but they are of the same type and are related to one another.

First of all I want to know if Allah exposes some sin of someone, **does it mean Allah hates that person and that person is doomed?**

Secondly what if that person decides to change himself, **does it mean that it was good Allah exposed that person for the betterment of his afterlife?**

Thirdly, **does Allah expose some sin of people in this world to punish them?**

Comment: Do a child's parents *hate* the child when he makes mischief? Aren't the parents just being strict to correct his behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Bismillah rahmani rahim, before anything I just don't think we can say that Allah "hates" anyone of his servants, at least not that easly (like chirk), actually that's why he's always ready to forgive us for our sins no matter how much we repeated them, but on the other hand Allah hates the sin itself, and hates the fact that we do it that he can get mad at us astaghfiro allah.

So if your sin got exposed, first of all it doesn't that Allah exposed it, and even if he did (which you can't possibly know) it doesn't means that Allah hates you, and yes it could be a punishement for something really bad things you did, not exactly that sin itself.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is punished in this world, that is a sign of Allah pushing them to return to the correct path. It does not mean Allah hates them.

Allah says:

> And we will surely let them taste the nearer punishment short of the greater punishment that perhaps they will repent. (32:21)

If Allah hates someone, he wouldn't give them Iman in their hearts and a yearning to repent and be forgiven.

So, if something bad happens to you in this life, take it as a lesson and learn from it. Repent to Allah, and hopefully, you will be saved from the worse exposing of sins which is on Qiyamah.

Whether a punishment was good for your afterlife or not depends entirely on what you do next. If you learn from it, then it was good for your afterlife. If you stay on your path, then it was nothing but punishment.